# API PUT /marketing/contacts/imports with restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, sendgrid-api-v3

Due to internal reason, I need to recode my servlet from Java to c#.
I am trying to upload a CSV file using the API PUT /marketing/contacts/imports with restsharp.
I cannot manage to send the file properly.

**Code Snippet**
Please fine below my java piece of code working:

```
    File file = new File(CSV);
    byte[] data;
    try {
        
        data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        HttpResponse<String> response2 = Unirest.put(URLSengrid)
        
        .header(processSendgridHeader(headerFromSengrid).get(0), processSendgridHeader(headerFromSengrid).get(1))
        //("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "aws:kms")
        .body(data)
        .asString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here the non working c# code:

```
byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(testPath);

var clientSecondCall = new RestClient(URLSendgrid);
var requestSecondCall = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
requestSecondCall.AddHeader("content -type", "application/json");
requestSecondCall.AddHeader("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "aws:kms");
requestSecondCall.AddParameter("application/json", "{"file_type":"csv","field_mappings":["e1_T","e2_T","_rf2_T","e4_T","e5_T","e12_T","e13_T","e14_T","e15_T","e16_T"]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
requestSecondCall.AddFile("file", file, testPath);
```

I spent a long time looking for an answer without success. Any help would be appreciated

Technical details:
sendgrid-csharp version: 9.*
csharp version: v4.0.303190

Comment: The typo in the content-type header might not be helping.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the way you send the file in your c# code.

The Java code is clearly using the **Body** of the request, while the c# code is using RestSharp.

Restsharp is sending files in as a **Multipart form**, which your server is probably not qualified to handle.

I would recommend using HttpClient object:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
request.RequestUri = new Uri( "Your Url");
request.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(yourFilePath));
request.Headers.Add("your header name", "your header value");

var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```